# Remove duplicates from List<T> in C#.net based in Property value

Tags: c#, collections

I have list of employees where each Employee contains Properties EmpId,EmpName,PathSuffix.PathSuffix column contains the values EmpPart1.lst,EmplPart2.lst,Emp3456.lst,EmpPart3.lst,Emp5667.lst....

So, Now my question is how to eliminate the duplicates in the employees based on pathsuffix column such that my final list contains only the EmpPart1.lst,Emp3456.lst,Emp5667.lst....(ie removing all part files except one).

How to achieve this  ?

**Input:**
List where each file contains FileName & FilePath.Some of the FilePaths end with Part1,Part2,Part3..whereas some doesn't contain any parts.My requirement is take only one part file ie the higheset one(SourcePart3 in below case)

```
**FileName        FilePath**
Test1.doc       SourcePart1.lst
Test2.doc       SourcePart2.lst
Test3.doc       SourcePart3.lst
Test4.doc       Event.lst
Test5.doc       CallPart1.lst
Test6.doc       CallPart2.lst
**Desired Output:**
**FileName        FilePath**
Test3.doc       SourcePart3.lst
Test4.doc       Event.lst
Test6.doc       CallPart2.lst
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual class definition (regardless how long it is) and sample input (as compilable code) along with sample output. That makes it easy for us to give you good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by creating our own `IEqualityComparer<Employee>` to compare our entities and determine if they are duplicates or not.

```
public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
     public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
     {
         return String.Equals(x.PathSuffix, y.PathSuffix);
     }

     public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
     {
         return obj.PathSuffix.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Supposing you have the following list:

```
List<Employee> employees;
```

It's as easy as calling [IEnumerable(T).Distinct(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
List<Employee> uniqueEmployees = employees.Distinct(new EmployeeComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A general logic flow for solving this would be to first

select first employee, save his path suffix to a variable, sequentially loop through the list removing any other employee's with the same path suffix value. then increment to your next employee, and repeat.

Also, it's usually easier to check for duplicates when inserting employee's into a list, but I'm without your code I'm not sure exactly how you want to be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Dictionary<string, Employee>`. Loop over the list once, check the dictionary using ContainsKey, if it returns true, move on, if not, call `duct.Add(employee.PathSuffix, employee);`

Then use `dict.Values.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider how you are storing your data.  I would put the path data into a List.

**Employee Object:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    public List<string> PathSuffix { get; set; }

    public Employee(int ID, string Name, string PathCSV)
    {
        EmpId = ID;
        EmpName = Name;
        PathSuffix = new List<string>();

        foreach (string path in PathCSV.Split(','))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) == false && path.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                if (PathSuffix.Exists(x => x.ToLower() == path.Trim().ToLower()) == false)
                {
                    PathSuffix.Add(path.Trim());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Samples of the Employee Object**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Employee> MyEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        MyEmployees.Add(new Employee(1, "User 1", "Path1,Path1,Path2,Path2,Path2,Path3"));

        Response.Write("Employee 1 Information:<br />");
        WriteEmployeeToScreen(MyEmployees[0]);
    }

    protected void WriteEmployeeToScreen(Employee ThisEmployee)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder paths = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        Response.Write(string.Format(
            "{1} ({0})<br />",
            ThisEmployee.EmpId,
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ThisEmployee.EmpName)));


        foreach (string path in ThisEmployee.PathSuffix)
        {
            paths.Append(string.Format(", {0}", path));
        }
        if (paths.Length > 0)
        {
            Response.Write(string.Format("Paths: {0}", paths.ToString().Substring(2)));
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```html
Employee 1 Information:
User 1 (1)
Paths: Path1, Path2, Path3
```